# Distance between $l$ and $\left( \begin{smallmatrix} 1\\ 2\end{smallmatrix} \right)$

Tags: linear-algebra, analytic-geometry

Let $l$={ $t\left( \begin{matrix} 3\\ 4\end{matrix} \right):t\in\mathbb{R}$ }. Find the distance between $l$ and $\left( \begin{matrix} 1\\ 2\end{matrix} \right)$.

Solution. **Note that $l$={ $\left( \begin{matrix} x\\ y\end{matrix} \right): -4x+3y=0$ }**.

So, the distance is $\dfrac {\left| -4.1+3.2\right| } {\sqrt {\left( -4\right) ^{2}+3^{2}}}=2/5$.

My question is: Why $l$={ $\left( \begin{matrix} x\\ y\end{matrix} \right): -4x+3y=0$ }? How did we obtain this?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: eliminate $t$ between $x=3 t$ and $y = 4t$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know single-variable calculus, you can think of this problem as minimzing the distance between $l$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$.

$$
\text{dist}(u,v) = \left \| u-v \right \| = \sqrt{\left \langle u-v,u-v \right \rangle}
$$

To find a function of $t$ giving the distance between $l$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$ we just use the distance formula.

$$
d(t) = \sqrt{(3t-1)^2 + (4t-2)^2} = \sqrt{25t^2 - 22t + 5}
$$

Now to find the value of $t$ that minimizes $d(t)$ we just solve $d'(t)=0$.

This gives us a value of $t=\frac{11}{25}$

now evaluating $d \left ( \frac{11}{25} \right )$ we arrive at the answer of $2/5$

In fact this is how that expression you gave for the distance between a line and a point is derived.